# What happened to Nebula when the Avengers time travelled?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

I watched *Avengers: Endgame*. I couldn't understand what happened to Nebula when the Avengers time traveled. It was Nebula who revealed the Avengers' plan to retrieve the Infinity Stones to Thanos. What exactly happened?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nebula from 2023 time traveled with the Avengers to 2014. While there, due to the fact that she has a partially cybernetic brain, her memories became accessible to the Nebula that was already there in 2014. Similar to how 2 computers on the same network can see each other's files.

Taking advantage of this, Thanos was able to find out about the Avengers' plans. He captured 2023-Nebula, and then sent 2014-Nebula to return to 2023 with the Avengers. In 2023, the 2014-Nebula set things up to allow Thanos, along with his entire army, including both 2023-Nebula and 2014-Gamora, to time travel to 2023.

The 2023-Nebula convinced 2014-Gamora to change sides; and together they escaped, and 2023-Nebula killed 2014-Nebula.

Answer (score 2):

Nebula from 2023 travelled to the past with the Avengers and was captured by Thanos.

Under torture or due to the "network connection" the Avenger's plan is revealed and Nebula (2014 version) replaced her and travelled back to 2023 with the Avengers pretending to be Nebula 2023.

Nebula 2023 travelled with Thanos in his spaceship through time but escaped with Gamora's assistance in time to kill Nebula 2014.

Hence in 2023 there is only one remaining Nebula.

Of course, Nebula 2014 technically still exists because Captain America went back, replaced the Infinity Stones and reset her timeline so none of the above happened (as far as Nebula 2014 is aware).

Comment: All true, except the last line. Reset the 2014 timeline? I don't think so or I would hope that the 2014 Thanos, Nebula and his entire army are killed by the actions in 2023. And returning the 2014 stones simply causes that timeline to continue without Thanos and Nebula. Because since Thanos learns about the plan before the 2014 stones have been removed and brought to 2023. Simply resetting them back in their timeline, would cause 2014 Thanos to still know about the plan and still want to have his plan executed. Or perhaps this is just one of those 'it is so because the writers said so'.

Comment: "Under torture she revealed the Avenger's plan" I don't think this is true. Thanos found out her plan because 2023 Nebula's electronic brain got "co-mingled" with 2014 Nebula's brain, so that Thanos was able to see 2023 Nebula's memories. There's no indication that 2023 Nebula voluntarily gave anything up.

Comment: @GeorgeDerpi The timeline *is* reset because *Infinity War* still happened.

Comment: @GeorgeDerpi They created a new version of 2014, one in which Thanos left, never returned, and Infinity War did not happen 4 years later in that version.

Comment: @Paulie_D No, *our* Infinity War still happened, because you can't change our past. But the *2014* timeline is changed. As Gendolkari mentioned, Thanos from 2014 travelled to 2023 and got dusted. He doesn't return, so no Infinity War in that alternate timeline.

Comment: That's my point *our* Ininity War still happened. It didn't for the Thanos who got dusted, That timeline technically never happened.

Comment: @Paulie_D No, that timeline still exists.